# why are prefix-TOTAL_FORMS, prefix-INITIAL_FORMS, prefix-MIN_NUM_FORMS, prefix-MAX_NUM_FORMS of management_form lists?

Tags: django, python-3.x, inline-formset

Below is the POST data being sent from my form back to the view. This is resulting in Validation Error ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

```py
<QueryDict:  {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": ["..."],
    "project_title": ["project test"],
    "project_number": ["543219876"],
    "project_status": ["Active"],
    "project_initiation_date": ["2019-10-10"],
    "project_alias": ["alias"],
    "project_description": ["description"],
    "estimated_total_cost": ["100"],
    "project_type": ["Capital"],
    "project_start_date": ["2019-09-16"],
    "project_end_date": ["2019-10-10"],
    "city_department": ["CDD"],
    "fundingsource_set-TOTAL_FORMS": ["2", ""],
    "fundingsource_set-INITIAL_FORMS": ["0", ""],
    "fundingsource_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS": ["0", ""],
    "fundingsource_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS": ["1000", ""],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funding_source_number": ["876543"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funder": ["cve"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funder_contact": ["scott"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-contract_number": ["876543"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-phone_0": ["123456789"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-phone_1": [""],
    "fundingsource_set-0-email": ["mar@gmail.com"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funds_type": ["Loan"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funding_amount": ["30"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-percentage_of_funding": ["30"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funding_agency_type": ["Federal"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-is_awarded": ["on"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-is_being_leveraged": ["on"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-funding_doc_type": ["MOU"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-date_funding_doc_submitted": ["2019-10-10"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-date_project_budget_docs_submitted": ["2019-10-10"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-have_funding_reimbursement_requests": ["true"],
    "fundingsource_set-0-date_funding_reimbursement_request_docs_submitted": ["2019-10-10"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funding_source_number": ["987123"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funder": ["observian"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funder_contact": ["aravind"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-contract_number": ["987123"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-phone_0": ["123456678"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-phone_1": [""],
    "fundingsource_set-1-email": ["mar@gmail.com"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funds_type": ["Loan"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funding_amount": ["33"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-percentage_of_funding": ["33"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funding_agency_type": ["Federal"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-is_awarded": ["on"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-is_being_leveraged": ["on"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-funding_doc_type": ["MOU"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-date_funding_doc_submitted": ["2019-10-10"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-date_project_budget_docs_submitted": ["2019-10-10"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-have_funding_reimbursement_requests": ["true"],
    "fundingsource_set-1-date_funding_reimbursement_request_docs_submitted": ["2019-10-10"],
}
>
```

This form has 1 instance of the parent form and 2 instances of the child form in Inline formset.

```
'fundingsource_set-TOTAL_FORMS': ['2', ''],
'fundingsource_set-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0', ''],
'fundingsource_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0', ''],
'fundingsource_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000', '']
```

are they supposed to be lists? and if so, what does each item in the list indicate?

Below is the template snippet I am using to render this formset

```
<fieldset class="form-group card card-body">
<h4>Funding Sources</h4>
    <div class="FundingSourceFormset card card-body">
        <h5>Funding Source</h5>
        {{ funding_source_form.management_form }}
        {{ funding_source_form.non_form_erros }}
        {% for form in funding_source_form %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>{{ form.funding_source_number | as_crispy_field }}</p>
                </div>
                -----
                rendered all formset fields as crispy fields
                -----
            </div>
        {% enfor %}
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create Project</button>
</fieldset>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/media/jquery.formset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.FundingSourceFormset').formset({
        addCssClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
        addText: 'Add additional funding source',
        deleteCssClass: 'btn',
        deleteText: 'Remove this Funding Source',
        prefix: '{{ funding_source_form.prefix }}'
    });
</script>
```

Am I doing this wrong??

Comment: Show the template.

Comment: I just added the template snippet to the summary

Comment: According to the docs for django-dynamic-formset, the `management_form` should be outside of the DOM element you pass to the `.formset()` method.

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a list.

Having multiple values for that management form means you're probably also POSTing it multiple times.

Check your template and/or rendered HTML – I bet you'll find multiple `TOTAL_FORMS`, etc.

Comment: I just added the template snippet I am using to render the formset. I am not submitting the form multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the position of the management_form as mentioned by @DanielRoseman above in the comments.

According to the docs for django-dynamic-formset, the management_form should be outside of the DOM element you pass to the .formset() method

The new template snippet looks like this

```
<fieldset class="form-group card card-body">
<h4>Funding Sources</h4>
    {{ funding_source_form.management_form }}
    {{ funding_source_form.non_form_erros }}
    <div class="FundingSourceFormset card card-body">
        <h5>Funding Source</h5>
        {% for form in funding_source_form %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>{{ form.funding_source_number | as_crispy_field }}</p>
                </div>
                -----
                rendered all formset fields as crispy fields
                -----
            </div>
        {% enfor %}
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create Project</button>
</fieldset>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/media/jquery.formset.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.FundingSourceFormset').formset({
        addCssClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
        addText: 'Add additional funding source',
        deleteCssClass: 'btn',
        deleteText: 'Remove this Funding Source',
        prefix: '{{ funding_source_form.prefix }}'
    });
</script>
```